# Python Idle keyboard shortcut for debug stepping

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

All IDEs I've used to date have keyboard shortcuts for stepping through the code while debugging.  For example Microsoft Excel used F8 to step to the next line, Shift-F8 to step over, CTRL-Shift-F8 to step out. Thonny uses F6, F7 and F8 for those functions.  All I can find for IDLE is buttons, which I find far less convenient, requiring a lot of mousing around when keystrokes are much faster.  Is there a way to map keys to these functions?

Comment: May I ask why you are not using freely available advanced IDEs?

Comment: Sadly IDLE is not the best IDE for python. see PyCharm, vs-code, or atom. If you like CLI, see pyd and it's extensions

Comment: We are working on the Debugger UI.  It is one of the less developed parts of IDLE.  I have made note of this suggestion and will check the current patch.  It seems sensible even though I have not seen it before.

Comment: I am just starting with Python on Raspberry Pi, doing most of my development under Windows 10 (x86) because my Pi is headless and the VNC Viewer is painfully slow over hard-wired Ethernet.  The only IDEs I knew about were Thonny and Geany (both of which are billed as for educational purposes, implying that serious development would be outside their scope) and IDLE.  I will try PyCharm.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried PyCharm and I like it!  I do have one problem: I can't seem to get it to know about the Pi GPIO ports. Specifically "import RPi.GPIO" causes it to say that it can't find it.  Any ideas?